# Regex to extract src attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match every src attribute that ends with jpg or png or gif and extract src string inside. I am not sure if the following regex that I came up with is correct, but it does give me src attributes with addresses. My question has to do with the possible problem of the following regex and how I can extract only the src string.

```
/src\s*=\s*(["'][^"']+(jpg|png|gif)\b)/g;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review. It might be on-topic (after some editing) on [this sister site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Why are people voting down? Let me know so that I can rephrase my question?

Comment: I don't see the clear distinction between asking for a code review and asking about a programming problem that I am not well versed in. Can anyone explain so that I can understand?

Comment: You said the code works, so you don't have a problem. You just have doubts about the quality of the code.

Comment: If you only look at the related questions on the right corner, there are bunch of questions in the similar format. I cannot accept your accusation without understanding the validity of your accusation myself.

Comment: On top of that, I am asking how I can extract only the src attribute out of the regex above. Who said I do not have a problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your regex is trying to do too much. Start by doing something like:

```
function img_find() {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var imgSrcs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
    }

    return imgSrcs;
}
```

Now, your regex has a lot less to deal with. (No whitespace, single vs double quotes, and so on.)

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), and don't (except for very simple situations) try to use regex for parsing raw HTML :)

So, given an array of image sources, you just need to select the `jpg`/`png`/`gif` ones:

```
/(jpg|png|gif)$)/i;
```

And then grab their file names, without the extension: (There are many ways of doing this; here's just one thing I've thrown together...)

```
/(.*)\.[^.]+)/;
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The reason I am using regex is that I am trying to collect image links that are embedded within javascript code, which I cannot parse for image tags. Since I am not familiar with regex syntax, I am still not sure how I can extract only the address part after matching 'src' in the beginning. I am sure that this has to do with the  basics, but could you please explain me on this?

Comment: `javascript code cannot be parsed for image tags` -- Yes, it can. Regex is not the right answer to this problem, because of the aforementioned issues such as white-space, single vs double quotes, and so on. Use the DOM, as I suggested, to get the image source. *Then* use a regex. Any pure-regex solution will have annoying edge case bugs, and will be extremely difficult to read and understand.

Comment: Or if you want to ignore my advice completely, then just use: `/src\s*=\s*(["']([^"']+)\.(jpg|png|gif)\b)/g;`, and the second match group will contain the file name. But as I keep saying, there are a hundred ways that this could go wrong... For example, what about a file named `thisisnota.png.exe`? Or, what if unicode quotes(https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html) are used? Or, what if the file is named `"file_with_a_'_character.png"`? ..... None of these things would be a problem, if you did it properly as I suggested.

Comment: I think I misled you by not clarifying myself. The javascript code I have does not have img tag itself. For example, I need to extract src from  codes such as : ... when('A').register("ImageBlockATF", function(A){ var data = {  'colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":"http://ecx.images-zone.com/images/I/d15sdgL._wgg1500_.jpg" ... which I believe is not possible to extract without regex.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, though. I understand that it is not recommended to parse html with regex. For my use case, however, I will try the regex you gave me.